# Why is my Raspbian command prompt grey?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, terminal, lxterminal

I was messing around in settings and updating a few things today and rebooted my Raspberry Pi running Stretch and went to open the CLI again and the prompt has turned gray and some commands like `ll` don't work.

I after messing about some more I

tried to `clear` my terminal to which it responded:

`'xterm': unknown terminal type`

Just guessing I typed `reset` to which:

`reset: unknown terminal type xterm
Terminal type?`

appeared. I tried resetting this and nothing seemed to work. I also tried pressing `ctrl + alt + F2` and making a new boot directory etc as recommended in an older post, however, this also didn't work.

Then responding to the `xterm` problem I tried `sudo apt-get install xterm` which was said to fix the problem in another post I read but that also failed. 
[image: grey prompt]
If you have any idea as to why this is happening please explain!

Answer (score 2):

The prompt and the `ll` alias are set and the TERM environment variable is modified in `~/.bashrc`. It seems that file isn't anymore executed on login. Check if it is available and not empty and can be executed on login. You should also have a look at the file `~/.profile` if it is available because this is the file that is executed on login. Look if it calls `~/.bashrc`. On my RasPi permissions look like:

```
rpi ~$ ls -la ~/.profile ~/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 3624 Sep 29 16:09 /home/pi/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  759 Jul 28 21:45 /home/pi/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the same return that you did for the `ls -la ~/.profile ~/.bashrc` command you recommended.  My `~/.bashrc` was also not empty. I still have yet to check if calls `~/.bashrc`.